# "facet" data is empty in Hybris Product List Page

Tags: solr, e-commerce, upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

I upgraded my Hybris project **from version 2005 to version 2105**.
But there is a problem in the Product List Page.
In the category-based page, the "facet" data is empty.
I have done all the necessary Solr indexing and I can see the products with their data in Solr. **So actually my Solr indexes are working successfully.**

Since the facet data is empty, no filter comes and there is no filtering process.
"Facet" data is not coming, but the products are coming with pagination.
In the photo I added below, you can see the facet is empty, but the result, that is, the products are available.
Is there some setting that needs to be done?

I would be very grateful if you could help with this issue. Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution :
The root of the problem is in **2105**
It was because the classes in search-and-navigation->solrfacetsearch were changed in the new package.
(**FacetSearchResultFacetsPopulator** facet data is null due to the change made in this class).

To solve this problem, I replaced the content of search-and-navigation->solrfacetsearch with the file from the **2011** version, so the problem was solved.

Comment: Hello Rabia,
Could you please share what you actually changed, preferably with images? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there seems to be no backward compatibility for Faceting in 2105 as it uses JSON facet API from Solr, if you have customized the behavior of either the *FacetSearchQueryFacetsPopulator* or the *FacetSearchResultFacetsPopulator*, you will need to upgrade your implementation to adapt the 2105 paradigm.
We had the same issue migrating from 1905 to 2205 and we upgraded our custom implementation to resolve this.